# What is the best way to share a folder so T-SQL can use it?

Tags: sql-server, windows, t-sql, shared-directory

I want to write in a shared folder inside my network through an T-SQL procedure but when I try to write, it says permission denied. I tried to grant full permission to everyone and it worked. I don't want to leave it like that though because that would just be another vulnerability in my companies network. What user does T-SQL use? And do you maybe know a way to write without granting everyone permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant the permissions to the account used by the windows service. You can find out which account this is in 2 ways.

1. SQL Configuration Manager
   Open up SQL Configuration Manager on your server, and you see this. The account name you want I have highlighted in a red ellipse.
   [image]
2. Command line
   Use the command sc to get details of windows services. If your SQL Server instance is the default instance on 'Servername' use

   `sc \\Servername qc MSSQLSERVER`

If you SQL Server instance is Servername\InstanceName use

```
sc \\Servername qc MSSQL$InstanceName
```

The account you want is listed as the `SERVICE_START_NAME` which should be on the last line.

Comment: I finally did it but now the windows PC with the shared folder says it couldn't find the name "MSSQLSERVER". This is what I got from the command 
SERVICE_START_NAME : NT Service\MSSQLSERVER

Comment: OK - write a new question and remember to say specifically what you were doing at the time you got the "couldn't find the name" error message.

Comment: I just allowed write and read vor everyone but not execute. Still thanks for the reply